# Is "'Light-Speed' Disk Access" really a thing?

Tags: performance, io

I just saw [an advert for Hyve hosting](https://youtu.be/KQq8A_ES7ps?t=56) on You Tube. One statement made me curious, they said they offer "*'Light-Speed' Disk Access*":

[image]

Is this just a fancy way of saying they have optical technology, like CDs and DVDs?

Or is this something new? My first reaction was that can't be possible - electricity isn't that fast is it? I'm in half a mind to ask them their connection to the moon. 2.6 seconds I hope.

<sup>[Also posted on Skeptiks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28097/22682)</sup>

Comment: What would light speed mean anyway when applied to a disk or data transfer in general? It's a speed measurement in `distance/time` and this is not a size you use to define performance characteristics for data storage devices. Fun fact: To reach (linear) light speed at the outer edge, a 3,5" disk would need to rotate with ~1 billion rpm.

Comment: Generally: Tim, you lack English understanding. "Light Speed" in market talk is also identical with "super fast, as fast as possible": In this case it has no reference at all to optical drives. I can have a "Light Speed Customer Service". What this actually means is undefined (in terms of exact parameters), but it stands for one "as fast as physically possible". In this case I would expect A Raid 10 of High Speed SSD ;)

Answer (score 3):

That phrase is 100% Marketing BS.

[image]